# autorun excel file in windows 7 using CD or Pen drive

Tags: excel, autorun, vba

I want to run my vba excel user form automatically as soon as i will insert CD or Pen drive in my system. I tried the autorun.inf file.. It is changing the label and icon of drive but the file is not running. I want this to use in my project so that users should not tamper my other files. I am using windows 7.

Comment: What does your autorun.inf file look like?

Comment: [autorun] 
open=C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe
icon=icon1.ico
Label=My long drive name here
UseAutoPlay=1

Comment: Instead of Excel.exe file i am trying to open calc.exe file

Comment: But .exe file is not running in windows 7